# Save Node's Data to Another Table After Saving Node

Tags: drupal-7

I'm building drupal module, i wanna make function that triggered after saving certain content type. example
after saving article, i wanna save article's data to like nid, title, type, status to another table.
I'm stuck here, please help me. this some code I've made:

```
//using hook_node_insert
//i just wanna save data from content type 'article' only.

function mymodule_node_insert($node) {
db_insert('mytable')->fields(array(
'nid' => $node->nid,
'title' => $node->title,
'type' => $node->type,
'status' => $node->status
))->execute();
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me what's the problem with this code? Yes, Rules is a better approach, but if it's a module then I don't see any problem writing a hook in node insert and inserting the data in another table. But yes, if you are using drupal sql queries... then I would suggest you write the install file and generate the table.

Answer (score 0):

The [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module will help you to handle this,

**

> The rules module allows administrators to define conditionally
>   executed actions based on occurring events (known as reactive or ECA
>   rules). It's a replacement with more features for the trigger module
>   in core.

**

You can use the "After saving new content" event for the content part.

In this you'll be able to use conditions on your rules to make sure the actions are only fired for your required content types.